# Using perfect fowarding in STL predicate

Tags: c++, lambda, stl, predicate, perfect-forwarding

**Does it make sense to use perfect forwarding in some STL algorithm ?** What will be the deduced type ?

```cpp
auto it = std::find_if(cont.cgebin(),
                       cont.cend(),
                       [](auto&& element){ return myFunction(std::forward<decltype(element)>(element)); })
```

I suppose the L-value version will be used (what about const ?), but what does determine that ? Is there other algorithms which would send a R-value ? I don't think so, because it would mean the predicate could be "consume" the element, whatever the result of the predicate.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't `std::find_if(cont.cbegin(), cont.cend(), myFunction)`?

Comment: Good question. That's because the rpedicated function is overloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deduced type of `element` depends on how the lambda is used within `find_if`.

`find_if` will never move by itself (you could pass a movable-iterator to `find_if`, but then it's not `find_if` that's doing the move, but the dereference operator on the iterator). `find_if` will pass the value returned by the dereference operator to the lambda, so in your case it's most likely<sup>1</sup> `const T&` (it could well be `T&` if you had a non-const container and used `begin`/`end`).

In both `const T&` and `T&` cases, `std::forward` will do nothing, so you will just pass the parameter to `myFunction`.

Note that the standard requires the predicate of `std::find_if` to not modify its argument, so if you have `myFunction(T&)` that modifies its argument, your code has undefined behavior.

You should **not** `std::forward` here since there is no reason to accept an argument in `find_if` using anything else than `const T&`, so a better version would be<sup>2</sup>:

```
auto it = std::find_if(cont.cbegin(), cont.cend(),
                       [](const auto& element){ return myFunction(element); });
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Some weird containers (`std::vector<bool>`) will not return a `const bool&` but a proxy-object, so your lambda needs to take a `const auto&` or `auto&&`, `auto&` will be a compile-time error.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Some people (a lot?) uses `auto&&` in these case, **without** the `std::forward` of course, because it's shorter and gives you consistent lambda (you use `auto&&` everywhere for the lambda).</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot for this complete answer.

Answer (score -1):

In general it could make sense to perfect forwarding an argument, but it depends on its internals: does myFunction takes advantage of forwarding or not?

In this particular case - as a predicate - it is not recommended: I suppose that find_if never moves elements when it calls the predicate.

But if it would then:

- if myFunction takes it argument by lvalue reference, then nothing happens, so perfect forwarding is just a syntactic noise compared to the simple `const auto&` case.
- on the other hand: if myFunction can take its argument by rvalue reference (consumes it), then `find_if` would return an iterator to an element which is in a `moved-from` state. And all other elements would be moved whose are checked with the predicate. Thats why I suppose find_if does not `move`s the elements for checking predicates.

For other algorithms, like `std::accumulate` ignoring the rvalue-reference case can cause performance issues.

Comment: Your explanation is wrong. Whatever `myFunction` is here, the deduced type for `element` will be a (possibly const) reference, because it's not `myFunction` that determines the type of `element` but what you send to the lambda, and `find_if` will always pass lvalue-reference, unless the iterator are move-iterator such as the one returned by `make_move_iterator`.

Comment: I think we are saying the same. I have just intended to answer to multiple questions, like: "Does it make sense to use perfect forwarding in some STL algorithm ?" Yes, there are algorithms where definitely worth to consider, eg std::accumulate. "As a predicate?" Never.
Anyways, thank you for your feedback @holt, next time I try to be more precise about formulating my answer.